# Django under httpd logging rollover: "Text file busy"

Tags: python, django, apache, logging, vagrant

I'm having problems with Django not rolling over logs as it should.  In my httpd error log, I'm seeing many statements like the following:

```
[Tue Sep 16 14:52:05.952416 2014] [wsgi:error] [pid 4420:tid 139708516480768] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Tue Sep 16 14:52:05.952527 2014] [wsgi:error] [pid 4420:tid 139708516480768]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/logging/handlers.py", line 77, in emit
[Tue Sep 16 14:52:05.952619 2014] [wsgi:error] [pid 4420:tid 139708516480768]     self.doRollover()
[Tue Sep 16 14:52:05.952646 2014] [wsgi:error] [pid 4420:tid 139708516480768]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/logging/handlers.py", line 142, in doRollover
[Tue Sep 16 14:52:05.952674 2014] [wsgi:error] [pid 4420:tid 139708516480768]     os.rename(self.baseFilename, dfn)
[Tue Sep 16 14:52:05.952692 2014] [wsgi:error] [pid 4420:tid 139708516480768] OSError: [Errno 26] Text file busy
[Tue Sep 16 14:52:05.952731 2014] [wsgi:error] [pid 4420:tid 139708516480768] Logged from file constraint_calculations.py, line 97
```

I'm running django under mod_wsgi on a vagrant box running CentOS 6.5, running with 25 threads via the [WSGIDaemonProcess directive](https://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/ConfigurationDirectives#WSGIDaemonProcess).

### Additional Information

The contents of the application log directory at the time of the error are as follows. My logging config specifies 4 backups.  I'm not sure if the fact that just #4 and the current file are left signifies anything.

```
[root@localhost logs]# ll fact_app/
total 180
-rwxrwxrwx. 1 fact fact 99939 Sep 16 15:46 fact_app.log
-rwxrwxrwx. 1 fact fact 83778 Sep 16 15:44 fact_app.log.4
```

When I'm running httpd, here is the list of processes I see.

```
[root@localhost fact]# ps aux | grep httpd
root      5565  0.0  0.1 101228  2832 ?        Ss   16:22   0:00 /usr/sbin/httpd
fact      5567  0.3  0.3 511280  7660 ?        Sl   16:22   0:00 /usr/sbin/httpd
daemon    5568  0.3  0.4 447620  8060 ?        Sl   16:22   0:00 /usr/sbin/httpd
daemon    5569  0.3  0.4 447620  8064 ?        Sl   16:22   0:00 /usr/sbin/httpd
daemon    5570  0.3  0.4 447620  8068 ?        Sl   16:22   0:00 /usr/sbin/httpd
root      5680  0.0  0.0 103248   816 pts/1    S+   16:22   0:00 grep httpd
```

The application logs (but not the httpd error logs) are in a VirtualBox shared directory.  I checked to see which process was accessing these files per [this suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19036016/oserror-errno-26-text-file-busy-on-vagrant-with-synced-folder) (via the command `watch -n 1 lsof logs/project-all.log`), but even as Django was throwing errors, this command indicated that the only process accessing the log file was httpd itself.

I know file permissions are a common culprit, but httpd and the wsgi process are both running as the same user (`fact`), and that user has full write and execute permission on the logging directory.

### EDIT

Per [Graham's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25877858/django-under-httpd-logging-rollover-text-file-busy?noredirect=1#comment40500407_25877858), here are what I believe to be the relevant mod_wsgi configuration directives:

```
# Outside the VirtualHost definition
WSGIDaemonProcess site-1 user=fact group=fact threads=25 python-path=/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages:/var/fact

# Inside the VirtualHost definition
WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
WSGIScriptAlias / /var/fact/fact-conf/wsgi/fact.wsgi

WSGIProcessGroup site-1
<Directory /var/fact/fact-conf/wsgi>
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Comment: I *think* I'm using multiple threads but just 1 process, and since [logging is thread safe](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/logging-cookbook.html#logging-to-a-single-file-from-multiple-processes) there shouldn't be a problem.  If this turns out not to be the case, I may implement the `sockethandler` solution suggested in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19235402/how-to-do-logging-with-multiple-django-wsgi-processes-celery-on-the-same-webse).

Comment: Have you verified that your code is actually running in mod_wsgi daemon mode. http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/CheckingYourInstallation#Embedded_Or_Daemon_Mode Add you mod_wsgi configuration directives to the question.

Comment: Just added them Graham. Let me know if you think something looks amiss. I appreciate your interest in helping!

Comment: Did you run the test to make sure everything is running in daemon mode? The configuration does at least show one process. To double ensure that not running in embedded mode set 'WSGIRestrictedEmbedded On' outside of VirtualHost.